# swift facebook education and occupation

Tags: swift, facebook

Designing iOS app and the user is logging into the app using their facebook login. I need to get the user's occupation and education from the facebook profile. I have been told I need initial approval from facebook itself, is this the case?

Any pointers on how I can get the user's occupation and education will be greatly appreciated.

Thanks,
Bruce

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be done fairly easily.

First You need to register your app on

https://developers.facebook.com

This will create an AppID that you can use for your App.

Parse and Firebase provides Facebook login that can be integrated with your app

For Example if you are using Parse server as your backend Server.
You need to declare a permissions array for this

```
let permissions = [ "email","user_birthday", "public_profile", "user_friends"]
@IBAction func FacebookLogin(_ sender: Any) {

    //var permissions = [ "public_profile" ]

    PFFacebookUtils.logInInBackground(withReadPermissions: permissions) { (user, error) in            if let user = user {
        if user.isNew {
            print("User signed up and logged in through Facebook!")
            self.displayAlert(title: "Sign up and Login Succesful", message: "Login Successful")

        } else {
            print("User logged in through Facebook!")
            self.displayAlert(title: "Login Succesful", message: "Login Successful")

        }
    } else {
        print("Uh oh. The user cancelled the Facebook login.")
        }
    }



}
```

Similar implementations exist for Firebase as well. Probably well documented than Parse server which is open source

Here is a complete list of what you can request from your users

[image: Permission]

Image Reference https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/permissions/